# passing array to servlet via ajax gives null parameter

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

new to ajax and not quite sure whats wrong.  I have:

```
var myArray = [2324.031536  ,
               2355.015241  ,
               2397.099387  ,
               2444.286019];

$(document).ready(function() {                        
        $('#submit').click(function(event) {
            $.get('VsPredictionServlet',{myArray:myArray},function(responseText) { 
                $('#text').text(responseText);
            });
        });
    });
```

and in servlet:

```
String[] myArray = request.getParameterValues("myArray");
```

but myArray is null in servlet.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this:

> $.get('VsPredictionServlet',{ "myArray": myArray},function(responseText) {
>
> ```
>             $('#text').text(responseText);
> ```
>
> });

you need to pass parameter as a string.

Comment: use `JSON.stringify`
data = JSON.stringify({
  "myArray" = myArray
});
 
$.get('VsPredictionServlet', data ,function(responseText) {

            $('#text').text(responseText);
});